# Is there a way to make a tests only project in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, testing, xctest

Trying to add tests for [FlockSwiftUtils](https://github.com/talk-to/FlockSwiftUtils/). The project has no UI so I don't want to have a project with app target. Xcode does allow "None" as `Host Application` for the target so seems feasible.

The build for the target succeeds, but `xctest` fails with error

```
Showing Recent Messages
xctest (41117) encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted. (Underlying error: The test runner failed to load the test bundle. Executable cannot be loaded for some other reason, such as a problem with a library it depends on or a code signature/entitlements mismatch.))
```

From logs:

```
13:35:05.753 Xcode[38272:7487908] Test operation failure: The test runner failed to load the test bundle. Executable cannot be loaded for some other reason, such as a problem with a library it depends on or a code signature/entitlements mismatch.
13:35:05.753 Xcode[38272:7487908] _finishWithError:Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=5 "The test runner failed to load the test bundle. Executable cannot be loaded for some other reason, such as a problem with a library it depends on or a code signature/entitlements mismatch." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The test runner failed to load the test bundle. Executable cannot be loaded for some other reason, such as a problem with a library it depends on or a code signature/entitlements mismatch.}
```

The code for this is available in [tests branch FlockSwiftUtils](https://github.com/talk-to/FlockSwiftUtils/tree/tests).

Comment: Why don't you just create a 'Command Line Tool' macOS project that includes FlockSwiftUtils? I know it's not exactly what you're looking for, but maybe this is just a limitation of Xcode?

Comment: FlockSwiftUtils depends on UIKit. :(

Comment: Then you probably have to create a blank iOS app, otherwise there's no way to execute the tests AFAIK

Comment: @GuyKogus that's what I have done right now (https://github.com/talk-to/FlockSwiftUtils/tree/master/Tests). Hoping to get a better way, someday.